# Present data in uitableview in email - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an email composer that I want to populate with a table view in order for the user to email what the app has produced to themselves. Is this possible?

Currently, my email composer is being prompted by a button within a table view controller. Is it easier to produce an entirely different 'email view controller' to gain more control over the email composition?

```
@IBAction func email(_ sender: Any) {

    let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail(){

        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mail.setToRecipients([])
        mail.setSubject("Hello")
        mail.setMessageBody("Hi Friend", isHTML: false)

        present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {

        showAlertWith(title: "Email unavailable", message: "Email not working")
    }

}
```

I've thought about setting a table view up programatically i.e. var emailTable: UITable = UITable(), but I have no idea how to get this into mail.setMessageBody.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: At some point, you would have to use `MFMailComposeViewController`. What you can do is have a specific body, and for that a specific UI for it.

Comment: try changing your email content into HTML and send them as Table . or use generate PDF using iOS framework and send that file as Attachment in the mail . Am not sure we can embed UITable in message body